# Array.pop() Isn't killing my setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written some code that when you click a button it adds an instance of a function to an array,

```
var objects = [];

$(document).on("click", ".addButton", function(){
    objects.push(new newObject(1));
});

function newObject(amount){
    setInterval(function(){ 
        addValue(amount);
    }, 1000);
}
```

So then every second each new object created keeps running the addValue function every second adding the amount.

The problem is when I try and destroy that function with objects.pop() it deletes the object but the setInterval doesn't stop running.

How do I make it destroy everything in that function and stop it from running?

Comment: `setInterval` returns a timer ID which you can use to cancel the interval via `clearInterval(timerId)`. Also, what is `addValue`?

Comment: Almost nothing about this makes any sense... calling `new newObject` just returns an empty object, has nothing to do with the `setInterval`, stopping `setInterval` requires calling `clearInterval` with the handle returned by that function, Array.pop doesn't 'destroy' anything, what is all this?

Comment: Just removing a running instance from some array isn’t going to stop it. You actually need to clear the interval, althought I’m not sure how to “link” it to the `pop`.

Comment: Jared, I realise that my code as written makes no sense, it does other things I just wrote a simplified version of my problem, erroneously thinking that the setInterval would be considered part of that object.

Comment: Why is this voted to close? It's clear enough what the poster is asking. There is clearly a misunderstanding of javascript arrays, but that doesn't make it a bad question - in fact thats what this site should be about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing quite like that in JS for setInterval. I would suggesting declaring a method to handle clean up.

```
// "Class" declaration    
function newObject(amount) {
    var id = setInterval(function() { 
        addValue(amount);
    }, 1000);

    this.kill = function() {
        clearInterval(id);
    }
}


// "Public" api for the data structure
var objects = [];

function addNewObject() {
    objects.push(new newObject(1));
}

function destroyLastObject() {
    objects.pop().kill();
}

// Event bindings
$(document).on("click", ".addButton", addNewObject);
$(document).on("click", ".removeButton", destroyLastObject);
```

Completely untested, but along these lines should work.

*EDIT*

This, imo, is a great resource for learning about different patterns within javascript - long but well well worth the read: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: No worries Steve. Checkout that link too, lots of good reading in there

Answer (score 0):

You got to find something to check against to clear the interval. I am clearing based on array length. It only executes once.

```js
// you got to find something to check against to clear the interval
var objects = [];

document.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log('click');
    objects.push(new newObject(1));
});

function newObject(amount){
 
 var interval= setInterval(function(){ 
     
         if(objects.length !==0){
        clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```